# Is there interest to install a regular (6-monthly ?) review of all tags and propose a combined update?

Tags: discussion, tags

Given two recent posts on meta on the topic of removing tags (conditioning and numerics), I was wondering if there is an interest among some users to install a regular "tag review". The idea is to look globally at all tags, see if there are any issues and propose a set of modifications to be approved by the community. Clearly, this should not interfere with ad hoc requests. I'm happy to volunteer to participate in such a recurrent action.

Comment: I would also volunteer my time to such a task.

Comment: Good idea! I am sure that cleaning up the tags will improve usability of scicompSE. I would also take part in these discussions.

Comment: @Geoff Oxberry: Hi Geoff, I'm open for suggestions on how to proceed here.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea.  I'm no longer a pro tem moderator, bud I'm happy to help out where I can.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe my answer will bump this post for Geoff to see.

Also notice in beta site,

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms.

But the question with any beta sites is that there are many useless tags, and users haven't been able to gain 5 or more scores on one to tag the synonyms. For example:

- There are tags created by mistake because the creator didn't enter the hyphen and the system interpreted one part of the tag as one tag, notable examples are [finite](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite), [elements](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elements), [eigen](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eigen).
- Synonyms, for example, [electromagnetics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetics) and [electromagnetism](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism); [data-visualization](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization), [visualization](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization), and [plotting](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting); [finite-element](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-element) and [fem](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fem).

Lastly my suggestion is that, like a site self-evaluation here: [Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/lets-get-critical-jul-2013-site-self-evaluation) , we should make a tag self-evaluation.